# NSString caused EXC_BAD_ACCESS, string too long?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, exc-bad-access

When my app gets to this, I receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
NSString *nameData = nameTextField.text;
NSString *emailData= emailTextField.text;
NSString *phoneData = phoneTextField.text;
NSString *serviceData =    serviceTextView.text;

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email_address=&contents=&form_identifier=538b7271-df83-41f5-84b0-db0fed518ade&form_type=1&empty_form_msg=Please%20fill%20in%20something%20before%20submitting.&1_1_10_40_First%2BName=%@&2_1_20_30_Last%2BName=&3_1_25_25_Company=&4_1_30_999_Email=%@&5_1_40_10_Phone=%@&6_1_50_0_Address%2B1=&7_1_60_-10_Address%2B2=&8_1_70_-20_City=&9_3_80_-30_County=&10_3_90_-40_Postcode=&11_2_100_-50_Comments=%@&submit=Send",nameData,emailData,phoneData,serviceData];
```

Is this because the data in this string is too long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that `stringWithFormat` interprets (some of?) the `%` characters as format elements, so that more than 4 arguments are interpreted. (e.g. `%20f` would take a float argument)

Try to replace all literal `%` (i.e. all but the `%@`) with `%%`.  [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) summarizes all the format supported by NSString.

Comment: Thank you!, i literally just figured this out before you posted !!